# How long will these vegan muffins last out of the fridge?

Tags: baking, vegan, muffins

I make these muffins with the following ingredient:

- Oat flour
- Banana
- Pea milk
- Walnuts
- Chia seeds
- Sesame seeds
- Cinamon
- Salt
- Baking powder

I am going to travel and want to bring some with me. I was wondering how long they would be good for without refrigeration.

Comment: Expiration dates strongly depend on the product itself. What can be stored without a refrigerator will retain its properties for a long time. But it matters whether you go to the Sahara or travel to the South Pole.

Comment: Travel how long ? what conditions ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a firmly answerable question, because  shelf life of foods of any kind depends on many factors.  Among them is the fact that the muffins can still be non-toxic, but taste terrible by becoming rancid, something that's a real danger with any baked good that includes nut flour.

For a comparison, though, most commercial vegan muffins say that [they should only be kept for around 5 days](https://ovenvia.com/what-are-vegan-muffins-made-of/).

You might get more useful information by asking "what can I do to increase the shelf life of these muffins" instead.